# Click not working first time

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone application.

Whenever I set a buttons visibility to collapse and I make it visible again I have to click on it twice to get it to fire the command it binds to. How can I make it fire after the first time again? It does not even hit any code at all on the first time. Both the visibility and button command is set through binding it to the view model properties.

Comment: Can we see the code that you're using to create the command?

Comment: as an alternative you can change the opacity property, so this button will remain in memory

Comment: I have the same problem: the button is in a collapsed grid. when I change the grid visibility sometimes I have to click the button twice. The first time the button seems to react (it flash to indicate the click) but no event is ever triggered in the application

Comment: @pierre poliakoff in the end I made a custom command that set the canexecute property

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using MVVM light?

If so I had some similar problem when I used ICommand. If you instead only use the build-in relay command, then that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Not using MVVM light, but using the pattern. I did some work around where I did not have to hide the button. Will give the relay command a go a bit later though

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from a "focus" issue. I suspect that the focus is confused by the change in visibility. The first click is then used to restore the focus.

To avoid this problem, I force the focus to be on the button just after changing the visibility

```
  private void RequestDialogBoxEvent(object sender)
    {

        this.DialogBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        this.buttonOK.Focus();
    }
```

with the XAML for the dialog box:

```
   <Border  x:Name="DialogBox" Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" >
        <Grid  Margin="0,20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Confirm ?"  />
            <Button x:Name="buttonOK" Content="OK" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```